# Adding new calculated columns in dataframe using formula from another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Below are two dataframes, `df` and `fmla`. The `fmla` dataframe stores the variable name and the formula expression.

Using `fmla` dataframe, two calculated variables need to be added to `df` (`purrr::map()`?).

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a,   ~b,  ~c,  ~d,
  1000, 500, 300, 100,
  1100, 560, 330, 110,
  1200, 600, 360, 120,
  1300, 650, 390, 130
  )

fmla <- tibble::tribble(
  ~variable,  ~formula,
        "e", "(a+b)/c",
        "f",     "e*d"
  )
```

If the calculated columns would have been manually added, the result would be similar to below calculation:

```
(result <- df %>% 
  mutate(e = (a+b)/c, f =  e*d )
)


result <- tibble::tribble(
       ~a,  ~b,  ~c,  ~d, ~e,     ~f,
     1000, 500, 300, 100,  5,    500,
     1100, 560, 330, 110,  5.03, 553.33,
     1200, 600, 360, 120,  5,    600,
     1300, 650, 390, 130,  5,    650
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically doing this in base R -

```
for(i in seq(nrow(fmla))) {
  df[fmla$variable[i]] <- with(df, eval(parse(text = fmla$formula[i])))
}

#    a     b     c     d     e     f
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1000   500   300   100  5     500 
#2  1100   560   330   110  5.03  553.
#3  1200   600   360   120  5     600 
#4  1300   650   390   130  5     650
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you have in mind, perhaps a little more automated:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)


fmla %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = formula) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(e = eval(parse_expr(e)),
         f = eval(parse_expr(f)))


# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
      e     f     a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  5     500   1000   500   300   100
2  5.03  553.  1100   560   330   110
3  5     600   1200   600   360   120
4  5     650   1300   650   390   130
```

Comment: Many thanks. Can there be one more way?
Being non-technical, coding is bit challenging. But after reading about tidyeval package, can the solution be something on the line of:

* for each row of `fmla` dataframe, invoke a anonymous function on the `df` dataframe, using appropriate `purrr` function.
* The anonymous function would take `variable` and `formula` as text argument, convert to symbol, and quote it (`enquo()`?)
* the function would prepare the mutate statement by unquoting the variable and formula.
* the function would execute the mutate statement to add the calculated column.

Comment: Your welcome. I edited my codes to use `parse_expr` from `rlang` package and now I'm thinking of a way to more automate this. I totally got your point. I will update it as soon as I come up with something. Just wanted to propose an effective solution maybe not the most efficient one but I will update asap.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) df[[x]] <<- eval(parse(text= y), envir = df),
   fmla$variable, fmla$formula)
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#      a     b     c     d     e     f
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1000   500   300   100  5     500 
#2  1100   560   330   110  5.03  553.
#3  1200   600   360   120  5     600 
#4  1300   650   390   130  5     650
```